# Use dynamic set of variable for template

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

My objectif is to write a generic role for nginx configuration.

I want to allow to define many snippets based on templates. Depending on templates the set of variable can be differents.

The list of templates are defined in host_vars:

```yaml
nginx_templated_snippets:
  - template: whitelist_open.j2
    file: whitelist_iprestrict.conf
    options:
      allow: "{{ default_whitelist + [ansible_facts.default_ipv4.address] }}"
```

the role looks like:

```yaml
- name: Add templated snippets
  template:
    src: "{{ item.template }}"
    dest: "/etc/nginx/snippets/{{ item.file }}"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0644'
  vars:
    "{'{{ nginx_template_options }}'}"
  loop: "{{ nginx_templated_snippets }}"
  notify: Test nginx configuration and reload
```

In this example, the variable `allow` is requiered in template `whitelist_open.j2` but depending on template the variable name can change.

I didn't manage to set the dynamic set of variables:

> ERROR! Vars in a Task must be specified as a dictionary, or a list of dictionaries

I tried many syntaxes but not sure that could be possible

Comment: I don't get why you want to add it to the `vars` of that task? Ansible variables do not have any visibility scope, like you would find them on other programming language, so, in your case, `item.options.allow` would be accessible in your template.

Comment: Actually my template is used in another context and the name of the variable is fixed